# Music at a Wedding

Tags: halacha, wedding, music

Someone told me that there is a requirement to have music at a wedding. He said that the Mishna Brurah says if one side does not want to pay for the music the other side can force them to pay for it. Is this true, and what is the source for it?

Comment: In some communities in Jerusalem there is a custom specifically to not allow musical instruments at weddings.

Comment: Yes following on from @DoubleAA's comment there's a well sourced article here - https://outorah.org/p/27279

Answer (score 1):

The Igros Moshe Yoreh De'ah siman 112 says that there is an obligation to take muscial items to a wedding. This also applies to the seudah that if the choson doesn't want to have a seudah, however, the relatives of the Kalah wants it we force the choson to agree. And the Biur Hateiv in Even HaEzer says that if a person marries and doesn't want to overload the wedding with joy and the relatives of the Kalah want to take the Kalah to dance with musical items the husband cannot stop them.

Comment: I seem to remember but cant find now that if there is no music here one weds in another town.

Comment: Didn’t R’ Moshe also forbid music all year round (except for simchas)

Comment: @KapinKrunch Yes he does in Oruch CHaim Chelek Alef Siman 166

Comment: So how do ashkenazi frum singers get around that psak

Comment: A person can't go around depressed they need some simcha

Comment: What does “depression” have to do with this

Comment: That is one of the reasons some allow people to listen to music.